# Merge yaml files and re-organize by values of key value list

Tags: json, yaml, jq

I have a list of yaml files, each describing a project, with a key `sdgs` which contains a list of numbers representing the Sustainable Development Goals.

I would like to merge all files and convert them to json in a different format, with sdg indexes as key, and related projects as list values.

Input:

```
---
# gnu_health.yaml
description: >
  GNU Health is a Free/Libre project for health practitioners, health
  institutions and governments. It provides the functionality of Electronic
  Medical Record (EMR), Hospital Management (HMIS) and Health Information
  System (HIS).
sdgs: [3]
name: GNU Health 

---
# a11y.yaml
description: >
  This Accessibility Project is a community-driven effort to make web
  accessibility easier by leveraging a worldwide community of developer
  knowledge.
sdgs: [10]
name: A11Y

---
# bahmni.yaml
description: >
  Bahmni is an Open Source hospital Management System focusing
  on poor/underserved and public hospitals in the developing
  world.
  It's aimed to being a generic system which can be used for
  multiple diseases and hospitals in different countries.
sdgs: [1, 3]
name: Bahmni
```

**Expected Output**:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "name": "Bahmni",
      "description: "..."
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "name": "GNU Health",
      "description: "..."
    },
    {
      "name": "Bahmni",
      "description: "..."
    }
  ],
  "10": [
    {
      "name: "A11Y",
      "description: "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to figure this out using jq's filtering system, even after reading the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) and other [awesome-jq](https://github.com/fiatjaf/awesome-jq) resources.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Current best effort:

```
# use as follow: yq -f $binDir/concat_sdgs.jq $srcDir/*.y*ml

# concat_sdgs.jq
{
  (.sdgs[]|tostring): [.]
}
```

This will not merge projects from the same sdg together unfortunately

**Current incorrect output**:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "name": "Bahmni",
      "description: "..."
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "name": "GNU Health",
      "description: "..."
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "name": "Bahmni",
      "description: "..."
    }
  ],
  "10": [
    {
      "name: "A11Y",
      "description: "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is that you're close.

For simplicity, I'm going to assume that the .yaml conversion to .json has already been done. Slightly adapting your filter, it's easy to see that:

```
jq '{ (.sdgs[]|tostring): del(.sdgs) }' a11y.json gnu_health.json bahmni.json
```

produces a stream of four single-key objects corresponding closely to what you want.

To combine them into a single object is a tiny bit tricky.  To keep things simple, let's first define a helper function which can be used to group single-key objects by key:

```
  def group_by_keys: reduce .[] as $o ({}; 
     reduce ($o | to_entries[]) as $kv (.; .[$kv.key]
```

Next, we'll use `inputs` with the -n command line option:

```
jq -n '
  def group_by_keys: reduce .[] as $o ({}; 
     reduce ($o | to_entries[]) as $kv (.; .[$kv.key] += [$kv.value]));
  [inputs | {(.sdgs[]|tostring): del(.sdgs) }] | group_by_keys

' a11y.json gnu_health.json bahmni.json
```

(Don't forget `-n`.)

If the ordering of the keys is important, then simply use this filter:

```
def sort_by_keys:
  to_entries
  | sort_by(.key|tonumber)
  | from_entries;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to produce the expected result. Instead of having a list of projects for each sdg key, I'm only seeing one project as object value to the sdg. 
If I could concatenate projects for each sdg, this would be perfect

Comment: I'm doing the -n.  It still only lists 1 project per sdg in the output. If you try to run this with 3 files, 2 of them having `sdg: [3]`, only one project will be returned

Comment: sorry about that, I've updated the question with a better example :)

Comment: The last bit is my current incorrect output. Please only look at the "Expected output' ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198223/discussion-between-fandekasp-and-peak).

Comment: Sorry for not fully understanding the expectations earlier.  All fixed.

Comment: Thank you <3 I find it very difficult to debug jq code, like how to figure out the proper code to write within the reduce. Do you have a tip for that?

Comment: `debug` is a good place to start with debugging. I think you'll find spending the time to master `reduce` and the `to_entries` family of filters worthwhile.